# PHP, MySQL - Multiple records in a DATE field

Tags: php, mysql

I was just wondering if it is possible to have multiple records in a date field? For VARCHAR I know that this works:

```
dater = CONCAT_WS(',', dater,  '$dater' )
```

However I just wondering if the same can be achieved with DATE field? Reason for this is tha every time record gets updated the date is saved. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Example:
19-12-2016, 20-12-2016, 21-12-2016

Comment: no. date is a single date.

Comment: i don't thinks its possible, and why is it you need to use the DATE field instead of Varchar?.

Comment: not possible a date has it's specific format

Comment: You can't and you shouldn't. Instead you should normalize your database by adding a new table that stores the dates and connects them to the existing table.

Comment: You should use a column, and if you want to save multiple records, you should use`json` to save the multiple records. First convert your dates to json & save them to a `text` column

Comment: @SaumyaRastogi  -- you're suggesting a denormalized, impossible to search, approach. Really? Maybe this is a good idea on a NoSQL dbms. Not in MySQL.

Comment: @O.Jones - Yeah, this works good only for non-searchable sql columns!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to add an updates table to your schema.

Let's say your main table is called `info` and has these columns.

```
   info_id  INT  (autoincrementing)
   info_val VARCHAR(250)
   info_last_update TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Then, you add a table called `info_updates`. It has these columns:

```
   info_update_id INT (autoincrementing)
   info_id        INT (points to info table row)
   info_update    TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
   info_why       VARCHAR(250)  (text describing update, if you like)
```

Then, every time you insert or update a row in `info`, you also insert a row in `info_updates`.

Then you'll be able to get an update history, with the most recent updates first, like this:

```
   SELECT info.info_id, info.info_val,
          GROUP_CONCAT(info_updates.info_update ORDER BY info_updates.info_update) updates
     FROM info
     JOIN info_updates ON info.info_id = info_updates.info_id
    GROUP BY info.info_id, info.info_val
    ORDER BY MAX(info_updates.info_update) DESC
```

If you stash your update timestamps into a comma-separated text field, none of this nice retrieval stuff will work properly.

This may seem like extra work. But, comma separated text fields cause much more extra work in the long run.

Prof. Richard Snodgrass has written a fine book on this topic and made it available. [Developing Time-Oriented Database Applications in SQL.](http://www2.cs.arizona.edu/~rts/publications.html)